# Execute code blocks in MySQL console

Tags: mysql

I have not used MySQL for many years.  Nowadays I have a need to work some code blocks for MySQL DB.  Supposing I need to write some records into to "visits" table. I have to write some dates from 2015-01-14 to today (2015-02-04)
When I write the codes below, MySQL console throws an eror:

```
delimiter $$
set @dateCursor = "2015-01-14";
while @dateCursor<=DATE(NOW()) do
insert into visits (visitDate, comment) select @dateCursor,"Another visit";
set @dateCursor = DATE_ADD(@dateCursor, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
end while;
$$
delimiter ;
```

I could have done operations like this at MSSQL Management Studio.

Comment: Do you have a procedure or function around that? If not, then make it so. In MySQL you need a shell if you have more than a query.

Comment: juergen many thanks. I want to do this without writing a routine. Yes, I tried this operation at my local database, so I am a root user :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do this w/o routine.